# Memo fields and forms DBASE PLUS

Tags: database, dbase

How can I display information within a memo field using a editor form component. 
I know that using an image you go with:

`form.image.dataSource = 'binary image_name'`

but with editor I do not know how to access the memo field and display its data.
Any sugestions,methods?

Answer (score 0):

Typically with dBase or xbase, you reference columns in a table like so:

```
 MyTable->MyField
```

or

```
MyTable.MyField
```

So in your example try:

```
form.image.dataSource = MyTable->MyMemofield
```

or

```
 form.image.dataSource = MyTable.MyMemofield
```

Comment: As I wrote in the previous post I need help using an editor component not an image.